# Chef: login / logon user after script runs

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I've got a chef deployment script that works well. To start the script off all users a logged off, application installed and then system rebooted with

```
  reboot "app_requires_reboot" do
    action :request_reboot
    reason "Need to reboot when the run completes successfully."
    delay_mins 0
  end
```

Instead of rebooting I want to have the script logon the user instead.

I can't see to find the command to make this work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you think "logon the user" means?

Comment: The computer has logged out to the windows login/lock screen. When the .Exe has finished installing i usually restart the whole computer and then the non admin user is automatically logged in on started. Instead i want to skip the restart and log in the non admin user from this screen

Comment: Chef is generally (if run as a service or via winrm) running a in headless session so it can't interact much with the graphical session even if one is present. Also a reboot is different from resetting the session, if you need to change kernel parameters then you need an actual reboot.